# Spring boot. Add jpa database connection and generate scheme

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and I need to connect to postgres database and generate scheme by Entities.
This is my maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I also have a `User` class anotated with `@Entity` and `UsersRepository` that extends  extends `CrudRepository<User, Long>`.
But it doesn't work. I got an exception:

```
2016-08-01 00:57:56.441 ERROR 17643 --- [main]
o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration':
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is. org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:.Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

What else should I do to connect to database and generate scheme?

Comment: Please share your `spring-data-jpa` configuration. Do you have your custom `DataSource` bean configured?

Comment: @AntonNovopashin This is all my configuration. I don't have a jpa configuration in application config and I don't need custom configuration, just simplest way to work with postgres database with jpa in my spring boot application, but I can't find any working examples in net

Comment: are sure you have only `application.properties` file. It looks like you do have a `yaml` configuration file. Make sure you have only one place for configuration. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Comment: @AntonNovopashin Yes, I'm sure that I don't have *.yml configs. I have an `@SpringBootApplication` config file but there are just beans declarations. May be I should declare there a DataSource? Can you show some working example, how to configure jpa in spring?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa